# How to know if a table exists in an Access Database in an OleDb connection

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, datareader, oledbconnection

I'm using the below code to connect to an Access Database using `OleDb` connection in `C# .Net`

How can I know if the table that I have hard-coded into the program actually exists in the file, so that I can show the user the appropriate message?

```
try
{
    var dbSource = "Data Source = " + source;
    const string dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;";

    using (var con = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider + dbSource;
        con.Open();

        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Concrete Design Table 1]";

            // How do I know the table name is valid? It results in errors when it is not?
            // How to prevent it?
            using (var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dataReader != null && dataReader.Read())
                {
                    // read the table here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You can get the list of tables with `var schema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });`, if I am understanding what you want correctly.

Comment: @svinja Thanks svinja for the clue, but can you tell me where in schema the list of the names are saved? I couldn't find it.

Comment: The code started to add up so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the list of tables with

```
var schema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
```

and go through them:

```
foreach (var row in schema.Rows.OfType<DataRow>())
{
    string tableName = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
}
```

or check for existence:

```
if (schema.Rows
          .OfType<DataRow>()
          .Any(r => r.ItemArray[2].ToString().ToLower() == tablename.ToLower()))
{
    // table exists
}
```

Ugly, I know. :(

Comment: the strange thing is that the tables exists in my exe folder database but it does not get displayed in the above code!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working solution I used (in VB.NET, but I guess you can figure out the C# variation):

```
Dim myTable As Object, TableSchema As Object

Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection
con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=" & myFileName & ";"

If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Open()
TableSchema = con.GetSchema("TABLES")

myTable = TableSchema.select("TABLE_NAME='MYTABLENAME'")
If myTable.length = 0 Then
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE MYTABLENAME;"
    nAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL error will throw `OleDbException` and you can [check `SQLState` for specified error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15952936/identifiying-exceptions-of-the-same-oledbexception-type). If the table does not exists, The code should be 3376 according to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb221208%28v=office.12%29.aspx). So your code should look like

```
catch (OleDbException e)
{ 
    switch (dbException.Errors[0].SQLState)
    {
        case "3376":
            MessageBox.Show(dbException.Errors[0].Message); // or any message
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```